# Creating a boxplot with error bars in python

Tags: boxplot

Another question, I have this data from my lab exercise

```
std = [10.17, 10.15, 10.13, 10.18, 10.21]
mean = [0.009, 0.012, 0.019, 0.04, 0.025]
name = ['control','Oligo','Rotenone','CCCP','KCN']
```

and I want to create a boxplot with error bars in Python, but everytime I try to create the plot, I get this error message

"only size-1 arrays can be converted to python scalars"

using this code or others alike found on other platforms

`fig, ax = plt.subplots()`

```
ax.bar(name, mean, yerr=std, align='center', alpha0.5)
```

What am i missing here? in the examples online it work perfectly.